# Smooth animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navbar with a function that changes it's size on scroll by adding a class named "shrink", it's working fine but when it adds the class and changes it's size it happens fast which doesn't look nice to me, i want to smooth this animation to make the shrinking look nicer but it's not working with me, here is my code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  min-height:800px
}

nav a {
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 13px 15px 13px 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 30px;
}

nav.navbar.shrink {
  min-height: 35px;
}

nav.shrink a {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav.shrink .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 25px;
}

nav.shrink .navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 5px;
  margin: 8px 15px 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Have you experimented with any css transitions (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) to apply a duration to the change of your css properties, rather than them being changed immediately?

Comment: Try adding Css "transition" property to nav element:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this. I just add only `transition` here..

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  min-height:800px
}

nav a {
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 13px 15px 13px 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s; 
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 30px;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

nav.navbar.shrink {
  min-height: 35px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s; 
}

nav.shrink a {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav.shrink .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 25px;
}

nav.shrink .navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 5px;
  margin: 8px 15px 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```